# Proper way to import from a module in Python so that it remains both importable and executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Let’s say I have 3 files:

`inc/a.py`:

```py
foo = 'bar'
```

`inc/b.py`:

```py
from a import foo
```

`c.py`:

```py
from inc.b import foo
```

If I run `python3 inc/b.py`, everything is fine. However, when I run `python3 c.py`, the following error shows up: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'`.

If I change `inc/b.py` to

```py
from .a import foo
```

the command `python3 c.py` now runs okay, but `python3 inc/b.py` fails with `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

How do I structure the code so that both `c.py` and `inc/b.py` remain directly executable? I’m using Python 3.9.5.

Comment: To execute a module within a package, use `python -m inc.b`, then the `import .a` will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, edit your `/inc/b.py` to look like this:

```
from .a import foo
```

and instead of running:

```
python inc/b.py
```

run:

```
python -m inc.b
```

But this problem you are having is pretty common and answered very detailed in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/15906059